# javascript/jquery code to obtain the form # of the form in which the user has selected some text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with multiple forms within it.

What I want is, obtain the form #, (eg second form is form #2) in which the end user has selected some text

I will use the form # to do some further operations on that specific form, using jquery and i need form # to be passed as parameter to the jquery calls that I have to make.

Is there some way to obtain this using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to find the # of the form:

```
var $form = $('#someFormId');
var index = $('form').index($form);       //OR, equivalent:
    index = $form.index('form');
```

Format:
  *`$element`*`. index(`*selector*`)`   (where *`$element`* is a jQuery object, and *selector* is a string which matches the collection to search in).
  *`$collection`*`.index(`*`$element`*`)`   (where *`$collection`* is a jQuery object, representing all elements, and *`$element`* is either a DOM or jQuery object, representing the element to look for.

Note: The parameter of the `index()` is very important. Have a close look at the documentation if you're not sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using focus, can allow you to set a variable to know the id of the form where the end user clicked into one of its fiels.

Html :

```
<form id="1">
  <input id="target1" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
</form>
<form id="2">
  <input id="target2" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
</form>
```

javascript (JQuery) :

```
$('form').each(function(){
    $(this).children().focus(function() {
      alert($(this).parent('form').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/qnsqZ/

Comment: kindly also tell me how to obtain the form # (ie the number of the form, with first form #=0) either using form ID (that you have shown how to obtain) or directly... Also, if I have the form ID stored in a variable, how do I select that form in a jquery expression (eg currently expression is ---jquery('input', document.forms[0]) ---, is there some way to modify this so that the form id obtained using your code (and stored in a variable) is used as parameter? Thank you for your help.